# Event After Every Model Save

Tags: magento

I would assume that there is an event after every model save.
How is this formatted, and is there a way to log all of these events?

This is useful if there is not a standard event declared within the moudle you are looking to extend.

Comment: Here is a [cheat sheet of all the events](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/) – the ones to watch out for are the ones with dynamic event names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I think the best answer would be based on all of the information that you've been provided.

1. A model does not necessarily need to fire an event at save/edit/delete however if it extends the Mage_Core_Model_Abstract class without overriding the default methods associated with save/edit/delete the events will be fired.

In order for an event to be unique to that model $this->_eventPrefix must be unique to that model

1. Logging these events often does not work

**To find the particular event you are looking for**

If you are using an IDE this should be much easier but you can also use utilities like grep.

1. Make a search within the module that you are working with for "$_eventPrefix ="
2. Use the list below to find the appropriate event suffix
3. Concatenate the two together and you should have your event

---

_load_before

_load_after

_save_before

_save_after

_save_commit_after

_delete_before

_delete_after

_delete_commit_after

_clear

---

To Log all events go to app/Mage.php line 446 and add:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::log($name);
```

Comment: *Logging these events often does not work* is misleading – it works as designed. `Mage::log` logs if logging is active *or* if you're in developer mode. (Look at line 800 of `app/Mage.php` to see.) Please do *not* edit code to force it to log. Instead, just set the `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` environment variable in the appropriate environment (Apache's, for example), and/or set `dev/log/active` in your store config.

Comment: Then, on another note, see that you can use the `Varien_Profiler` to observe the `dispatchEvent` calls, and you don't need to edit that code, either. Enable the profiler in your config at **System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug**.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::afterCommitCallback](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php#L336) - it has a generic event *and* an event dispatched by the prefix of the specific model being saved.

```
/**
 * Callback function which called after transaction commit in resource model
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function afterCommitCallback()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_commit_after', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_commit_after', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

Whether you want this or

```
/**
 * Processing object after save data
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
protected function _afterSave()
{
    $this->cleanModelCache();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_after', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

depends on whether you care if the data has actually been written to the database or not when you run your event handler.

When Magento sees a call to `Mage::dispatchEvent` it will call any public model class registered for that specific event name. So the real place to look for events is in the config.xml for the module/models you're interested in. The xml is not likely to be programmatically generated, so you don't have to fuss around with guessing `_eventPrefix` values. You know the event suffix you want, so just look in configuration for events with names ending with that suffix.

If you have an installed store, you can use [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) to search the config.xml. (It has a config:get command that you can use to search, but I prefer `config:dump` to a file, followed by using an xml parser and xpath to search through the result.)

Comment: I was able to track that down however 
http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin/catalog_product_attribute/
Save a product attribute and add a value:

        var_dump($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_commit_after');
        die()
        Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_commit_after', array('object'=>$this));

        Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_commit_after', $this->_getEventData());
        return $this;

I get: string 'core_abstract_save_commit_after'
I have a feeling If I listen to that I will cause a large reduction in performance?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your comment – If you're dumping this output in the abstract and then dying you're probably missing a lot of good information.

Comment: I think you might want `catalog_entity_attribute_save_commit_after`.

Comment: Cool , now how would one come to that answer?

Comment: @ajameswolf it's a guess – I looked at models with eventPrefixes I thought might be what you wanted. The thing I think you're missing is that if you `die()` in your testing you only see the *first* time that function is called.

Comment: Now were getting somewhere. So if I know the event prefix:
Line 75 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Entity/Attribute.php
I can then look in Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php for $this->_eventPrefix to extrapolate what events might be fired.

Comment: @ajameswolf Edited, hope this helps more.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Definately check out the n98-magerun im currently using Commercebug which does some of the stuff mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I always put a log into `app/Mage.php` into `dispatchEvent() method`

```
...
Mage::log($name, array_keys($event_data));
...
```

Then I refresh the page in the browser where I need to apply a custom event action and then look into system.log to see what events happen on my page.

Comment: thahts a good answer I saw earlier by Alan Storm however for whatever reason not all events are logged any idea why this might be?
For example in saving an eav attribute option value I get

Comment: 2013-10-12T18:04:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): resource_get_tablename
2013-10-12T18:04:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): resource_get_tablename
2013-10-12T18:04:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): resource_get_tablename
2013-10-12T18:04:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): resource_get_tablename
2013-10-12T18:04:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): resource_get_tablename
2013-10-12T18:04:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): resource_get_tablename
2013-10-12T18:04:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): core_collection_abstract_load_before
2013-10-12T18:04:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): core_collection_abstract_load_after
2013-10-12T18:04:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): core_collection_abstract_load_before

Comment: @ajameswolf `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` before `Mage::run()` in index.php will work

Answer (score 0):

Just need to put something like below in config.xml:

```
    <global>
    <events>
        <catalog_entity_attribute_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <yourextension_save_commit_after_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourextension/save_commit_after_observer</class>
                    <method>yourMethod</method>
                </yourextension_save_commit_after_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_entity_attribute_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Comment: I know the what now I want an understanding of how i get the answer.
For example could I assume that I could always look into a module find the particular model and just append _save_commit_after to its node to know the event? Is this always true?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. There is a _save_before and _save_after events after every model save, such as catalog_product_before_save, catalog_product_after_save, customer_address_before_save, customer_address_after_save, etc.

You can refer to this link below for more complete information about how to use it and the complete list of all events in Magento.

Source: http://www.vjtemplates.com/blog/magento/events-and-observers